# Auto Renewable Subscription Free Trial Not Working

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I have been trying to add a free trial to my Auto-Renewable subscription in itunes connect. Currently I have added the duration of 1 month trial for a 1 month subscription, however in the app during the purchase flow there is no mention of the trial. Instead it gives the typical dialog "your subscription will start  on ...."

Am I missing something? Do I need to enable free trials in a different manner? I have tried using a sandbox user to test in a dev build on a IAP that was not cleared for sale. I have also tried testing on a normal account with an IAP that is currently available and cleared for sale.

PS: please let me know if I should post this kind of question somewhere else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create a new subscription product and submit to review. Only after that, I was able to test. Without sending it to review, I wouldn't be able to retrieve it in the app.

Answer (score 0):

We have an auto-Renewable subscription with free trial. You don't need anything else in addition.

Have you modified an existing already approved purchase or is it a new one? Try creating a new IAP, send it for approval and once cleared for sale test it with a sandbox user.

Comment: I created a new one for testing only but didn't send for review but it's marked as `Cleared for sale`. The current one has no free trial but I changed it for a few minutes and it didn't work too. After changing the current one, it didn't change its status, it stayed `Approved`. Should it change?